# Translation of "to substitute for"?

Tags: word-choice

I'm writing an email to a teacher and I'm trying to say "two weeks ago, you substituted for the teacher of my class". I'm trying to figure out how to say "substituted" and I haven't been able to figure out the right word in the context of a class. I've found 替代，代替，取代, etc., and I can't figure out which one's correct in this context.

Comment: **ichacha** ：substitute teacher    代课教师; 代课老师... 
**bkrs** ：代课[take over a class for an absent teacher; teach for an absent teacher] 指在某个老师有事及生病时, 替他讲课，学校中教师因故请假或临时离职，由他人代替授课，称为「代课」。to teach as substitute for absent teacher
take over a class for an absent teacher:
代课教师 a supply teacher
substitute-teach
替我代课行吗？ Will you substitute-teach for me?
代替专职教师授课。

 #31268

Comment: It is rather impolite to say "you substituted for the teacher of my class" whether in English or in Mandarin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be“两周前您代我们班老师讲课”
I've made subtle changes In the translation to make it natural and polite.

Answer (score 1):

'you substituted for the teacher of my class' = 你给我们班代课